# What's the different of Program and ProgramArguments

Tags: ios, macos, jailbreak, launch-daemon

Is there any reference to tell the difference between  'Program' and 'ProgramArguments' in launchdaemon.plist?

I saw some plist only have 'ProgramArguments', but some also have 'Program', I want to make a clear understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a bit confusing, but in most cases both forms are valid.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html):

> **Program < string>**
>   This key maps to the first argument of [execvp(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/execvp).  If this key is missing, then the first element of the array of strings provided to the `ProgramArguments` will be used instead.  This key is required in the absence of the `ProgramArguments` key.
>
> **ProgramArguments < array of strings>**
>   This key maps to the second argument of [execvp(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/execvp).  This key is required in the absence of the `Program` key. Please note: many people are confused by this key. Please read [execvp(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/execvp) very carefully!